# Constructors in javascript

Tags: javascript

how to declare parameterized constructors in JavaScript?? How it can be achieved in JavaScript??

```
 public class A()
    {
     //variable declaration
     public A()
     {
      //do something
     }

     public A(int a)
     {
      //do something
     }

     public A(int a,int b)
     {
      //do something
     }
    }
```

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. Period. You may have only one constructor, but choose different behaviors depending on arguments' types (e.g. `typeof a == 'undefined'`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Class = function(methods) {   
    var klass = function() {    
        this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);          
    };  

    for (var property in methods) { 
       klass.prototype[property] = methods[property];
    }

    if (!klass.prototype.initialize) klass.prototype.initialize = function(){};      

    return klass;    
};
var Person = Class({ 
    initialize: function(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age  = age;
    },
    initialize: function(name, age, gender) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age  = age;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
}); 

var alice = new Person('Alice', 26);
var rizwan = new Person('riz', 26, 'm');
alert(alice.name + ' - alice'); //displays "Alice"
alert(rizwan.age + ' - rizwan'); //displays "26"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5NPpR/
http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/create-an-object-oriented-javascript-class-constructor.html#fbid=OJ1MheBA5Xa

Answer (score 1):

Any function in javascript can be a constructor

```
function A(paramA, paramB) {
    this.paramA = paramA;
    this.paramB = paramB;

    //do something
}

A.prototype.method1 = function(){
    console.log(this)
    console.log('Inside method 1' + this.paramA)
}

var a = new A(1, {name: 'Name'});
console.log(a.paramA);
console.log(a.paramB.name)
a.method1()
```

All instance variables can be created using `this.<variable-name>=<value>;`.
Instance methods can be created using the `prototype` property of the constructor `function`.

You can read more about constructors
[Simple “Class” Instantiation](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-class-instantiation/)
[Simple JavaScript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/)

You also can check whether a parameter exists using

```
if(paramB == undefined) {
    //do something if paramB is not defined
}
```

Comment: I think the 3rd line of code should be 'this.paramB = paramB' in order to work (can't make a 2 char edit to fix it though)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not support overloading based on argument definitions.

Write a single function and check which arguments were received.

```
function A(a, b) {
    if (typeof a === "undefined") {
        // ...
    } else if (typeof b === "undefined") {
        // ...
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```